# Tema do site randômico com troca a cada 30min

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, random, temas

estou precisando que meu site troque o tema de maneira randômica a cada 30 min. Então a lógica seria:

Usuário entra no site agora e o visualiza na cor azul (que á a padrão), mas se este mesmo usuário voltar daqui a 30 min ele deveria visualizar o site em uma das outras duas cores Laranja ou Verde.

Não sou programador mas com muito esforço e enchendo o saco de alguns amigos consegui chegar no código abaixo que está funcionando parcialmente.

Ele troca a cor do site a cada X tempo até ai OK, mas o problema é que sempre que o usuário retorna ao site ele o visualiza na cor azul padrão.

Alguém sabe como resolver está ultima e importante parte? Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="bones-stylesheet-css" href="http://www.mople.com.br/wp-content/themes/mople/library/css/mople-theme-1.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/library/js/jquery.cookie.js" ></script>

<script>
            setInterval(function (onload) {
                if ($.cookie("css") !== null) {
                    console.log('cookie existe');
                    $("#bones-stylesheet-css").attr("href", $.cookie("css"));
                }
                else {
                    console.log('cookie expirou');
                    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) - 1;

                    var styleSheet = $(".bt-theme button").eq(random).attr("rel");

                    $.cookie("css", styleSheet, { expires: 1 / 100, path: '/' });
                    $("#bones-stylesheet-css").attr("href", $.cookie("css"));
                }

                console.log($("#bones-stylesheet-css").attr("href"));
            }, 10000);
        </script>
```

Comment: Um problema é que a sua função está sendo executada a cada 10 segundos, mas não quando o site é carregado. Então por até 10 segundos o site pode ficar no tema default. Será que esse cookie não está sendo escrito em outro lugar?

Comment: Coloquei 10 seg para poder visualizar a troca do CSS sem ter de esperar 30 min. Mas mesmo aumentando para qualquer outro tempo o problema continua.

Comment: Sim, justamente porque a primeira vez vai demorar o tempo que você colocou para executar. O setInterval() não executa a primeira vez imediatamente. O tema azul deve ser o default que vem do servidor, correto? Num servidor com Javascript desligado, o default seria azul?

Comment: Sim o azul é o default. O certo seria colocar uma variável no lugar do caminho do CSS? Pois, pensei em ir por este caminho mas não sei como chegar lá.

Comment: Tente o segunte: mova todo o código function (onload) { ... } para uma função, chame a função dentro do setInterval(), e também chame a função em seguida, para que ela seja executada imediatamente ao carregar. Talvez resolav.

Comment: eu sei que faz parte da pergunta, mas você *tem* que fazer essa troca a cada 30 min, necessariamente? voce nao poderia simplesmente randomizar a cor toda vez que o usuário entra, independente do tempo? facilitaria um bocado

Comment: Oi Caio eu ainda não tentei a opção do @epx (provavelmente vai dar algum erro simples que eu não conseguirei resolver)  mas  posso ir por este caminho sim de deixar sempre randômico. Como ficaria o código?

Comment: @PetersonRamos, estou construindo uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

Bom, pelo que eu entendi do código que você postou, você tem 3 arquivos `.css` diferentes, e você está tentando randomizar qual deles vai ser carregado e usado pela página. Como eu sugeri nos comentários, talvez seja mais inteligente fazer essa randomização toda vez que o usuário entra na página, e não *necessariamente* a cada 30 minutos. Guardar esse tempo pode ser feito com `cookies` ou `localStorage` (isso falando exclusivamente do lado do cliente) mas uma sessão anônima já pode quebrar a lógica, fora que, pelo que percebi, a sua randomização não leva em conta o `css` que estava aplicado antes do `cookie` expirar será excluído da próxima randomização. Ou seja, você pode acabar trocando, após 30 minutos, o `arquivo1.css` pelo `arquivo1.css`!

Portanto, **vou basear a minha resposta em uma randomização instantânea**, e não a cada 30 minutos, conforme você pediu nos comentários. Caso você a aceite, talvez seja interessante editar a pergunta. A minha resposta também não levará em conta a verificação do `css` anterior.

Vou dar duas soluções: Uma mudando o `href` da tag `<link>`, conforme o seu código, e outro alterando a classe da tag `<body>`, o que acho mais interessante, pois você pode concentrar todo o seu `css` em um arquivo só.

1. Alterando o `<href>`

   De acordo com esta linha

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" id="bones-stylesheet-css" href="http://www.mople.com.br/wp-content/themes/mople/library/css/mople-theme-1.css" type="text/css" media="all">
   ```

   Tirei a conclusão (e assumo como verdade a partir de agora) que seus arquivos `.css` tem os nomes

   ```
   mople-theme-1.css
   mople-theme-2.css
   mople-theme-3.css
   ```

   Com `javascript` puro, você pode criar o arquivo `.css` dessa maneira:

   ```
   var _random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
   var _href = 'http://www.mople.com.br/wp-content/themes/mople/library/css/mople-theme-' + _random + '.css';


   var _link = document.createElement('link');
   _link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
   _link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
   _link.setAttribute('href', _href);
   var _head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   _head.appendChild(_link);
   ```

   Isso faz com que, a cada vez que a página for carregada, um dos 3 arquivos seja carregado juntamente. Vale lembrar que isso não garante que toda vez será um arquivo diferente, apenas garante que será um dos 3.
2. Alterando a classe da tag `<body>`

   Eu acho essa opção um pouco mais válida, uma vez que você teria apenas um arquivo `.css` para manter. Supondo que você tenha classes do tipo

   ```
   .tema-1{}
   .tema-2{}
   .tema-3{}
   ```

   Que controlem a sua cor de fundo, por exemplo, e que todo o resto do seu tema cascateie a partir delas (i.e., o seletor `h1` para o `.tema-1` seria `.tema-1 h1{}`, e assim por diante, você pode adicionar a classe à tag `<body>` randomicamente, de uma maneira similar ao exemplo anterior. Usando puro `javascript`

   ```
   var _random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
   var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
   _body.className = 'tema-' + _random;
   ```

   Você pode ver um exemplo básico desse funcionamento [nessa pen](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/BoyBwN). A cor de fundo muda cada vez que você faz um reload, e a cor do texto do `<h1>` muda também, de acordo com o tema.

**EDIT**

Consegui chegar em uma solução onde a cada 30 minutos, o arquivo `.css` que será carregado é diferente, garantindo que não será igual ao anterior (ou seja, trocar o `arquivo1.css` por `arquivo1.css`.

Basicamente, crio dois `cookies`: o primeiro, chamado `last`, guarda uma referência a qual foi o último arquivo que foi criado. O segundo, denominado `css`, recebe o valor *true* e tem uma validade de 30 minutos. Quando ele deixa de existir, eu uso o valor guardado em `last` para garantir que ele não seja o próximo a ser criado. Fiz alguns poucos testes, e parece-me que está tudo correto. Veja se o código lhe atende e me avisa. Solução em puro JavaScript

**EDIT 2**

Faltava recriar o cookie que controlava a expiração do tempo. Criei um método que faz exatamente isso. Veja o código alterado

```
function getCookie(cname) { //método retirado do site da W3C
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function createStylesheet(_file){
    var _href = 'http://www.mople.com.br/wp-content/themes/mople/library/css/' + _file + '.css';
    var _link = document.createElement('link');
    _link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    _link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    _link.setAttribute('href', _href);
    var _head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    _head.appendChild(_link);

    document.cookie = "last=" + _file; //cria um cookie dizendo qual foi o ultimo css
}

function createExpireCookie(){
    var _date = new Date();
    _date.setTime(_date.getTime()+(30*60*1000));

    var _expires = ";expires=" + _date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "css=true"+ _expires; //cria cookie com validade de 30 minutos 
}

if(null == getCookie('last')){ //nao existe cookie do ultimo arquivo
    createStylesheet('mople-theme-1');
    createExpireCookie();
} 
else if (null == getCookie('css')){ //existe cookie referente ao ultimo css, mas já se passaram 30 minutos
    var _sheets = ['mople-theme-1', 'mople-theme-2', 'mople-theme-3']; //possíveis arquivos
    var _index = _sheets.indexOf(getCookie('last'));

    _sheets.splice(_index, 1);  //remove o ultimo do array de possibilidades

    createStylesheet(_sheets[Math.floor(Math.random()*_sheets.length)]); //cria um css randomizando as possibilidades do array
    createExpireCookie();

};
```

Comment: Oi Caio, para mim a melhor opção é a primeira pois como estou trabalhando com o less ficou bem mais fácil separa o CSS em 3 folhas.

Comment: Oi Caio, para mim a melhor opção é a primeira pois como estou trabalhando com o less ficou bem mais fácil separa o CSS em 3 folhas. Pois só precisei separar o arquivo variable.scss e chamo todas a cores por ali. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda e seu código funcionou 90% o único problema que ainda tenho é que a cada mudança de página o site esta trocando de cor. Tentei resolver isto com window.sessionStorage, pois depois do que você comentou sobre o cookie achei que fosse a melhor maneira, mas não tive sorte. Você tem alguma sugestão para resolver este último ponto?

Comment: Obrigado Caio vou testar hoje e noite e  te dou um feedback

Comment: Oi Caio, infelizmente não funcionou a cor do site muda a cada refresh ou entrar na sala. Alguma sugestão

Comment: @PetersonRamos ta lá

Comment: Oi Caio, infelizmente não funcionou a cor do site muda a cada refresh ou entrar em alguma página. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: @PetersonRamos aqui está funcionando tudo certinho, inclusive com referência aos seus arquivos `.css`.

Comment: Oi @caio-felipe-Pereira, desculpe a demora em responder o código sim funciona mas há um pequeno problema. O CSS é adicionado a página pelo JS, e depois que ela é carregada tudo fica guardado dentro do Cookie como deveria ser. Mas quando passarmos para a outra página ela verifica que o Cookie existe e então não roda o JS e como é ele quem aplica o CSS ela fica sem estilo. Quando colocamos um tempo de vida de alguns segundos no Cookie para testar tudo fica ok, mas para tempos mais longos o problema aparece.

Comment: Percebi o problema pois tudo começava OK e de repente ao navegar as páginas perdiam o estilo. Apliquei um alert no JS para verificar o que as variáveis estavam retornando e ele também parava de funcionar de uma hora para outra. Então, reparei que que ao limpar o Cookie do navegador tudo voltava a funcionar, CSS era aplicado e alert pipocava na tela com o valor das variáveis. Com isto conclui que uma vez gerado o Cookie o navegador não executa mais o JS e com isto não aplica o CSS. Você tem alguma sugestão para este último problema?

Comment: Cara quero agradecer imensamente sua ajuda, e se um dia precisar de ajuda em questões de design, usabilidade, arquitetura de informação e CSS para desktop ou mobile estou a disposição para ajuda-lo.

Comment: @PetersonRamos, aí tudo depende de como você chama esse JavaScript internamente nas suas páginas vai criar um `.css` sempre que for chamado. você pode reutilizá-lo conforme achar necessário